# multiple forms with same model and action in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have this form multiple times on the same page in angular2 to send the message, but I am not sure how can I send the value to the action since it will conflict, is there any angular2 way for such scenarios or have to go with jquery select value function?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">

                <textarea class="validate"
                (ngModel)="msgmodel.message" name="message"></textarea>

               <input type="text" class="hidden" 
                      (ngModel)="msgmodel.parentid" name="pid" 
                      [value]="poo.message.Messageid">
       </div>

       <button type="submit" (click)="sendmessage(msgmodel)" >Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What does "send the value to the action" mean? What conflict?

Comment: suppose i have to send the message text to the function in the script i can use model for that but since there are multiple forms it conflicts doesnt know where to take value from

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846946/how-to-push-and-update-deep-nested-values-in-angular2-and-maintain-ui-state

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a hidden input with unique value in each form.